# Scala data structure and complexity O(1)

Tags: scala, data-structures

Today I had an interview about Scala and request was:

Implement a data structure with fixed size N , with these functionalities:

- get(index)
- set(index,value)
- setall(value)

**The complexity should be O(1)**

```
example:
   val ds = DS(100)
   ds.set(4,5)
   ds.get(4) //would return  5
   ds.set(1,4)
   ds.setall(10)
   ds.get(4) //would return  10
   ds.get(7) //would return  10
   ds.set(1,7)
   ds.get(1) //would return  7
```

Please find code that I have sent below.
My question would be **Is this right solution and if there is a better way of doing it ?**

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

trait Operations {

  def get(index: Int): Int
  def set(index: Int, value: Int)
  def setall(value: Int)
}

class DS(N: Int) extends Operations {

  var myMutableHashMap = new HashMap[Int, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)

  def get(index: Int) = myMutableHashMap(index)

  def set(index: Int, value: Int) = {
    if (index <= N) myMutableHashMap += (index -> value)
  }

  def setall(value: Int) = {

    myMutableHashMap = new HashMap[Int, Int]().withDefaultValue(value)
  }

}

object Task {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val ds = new DS(100)

    ds.set(4, 5)
    ds.get(4)

    println(ds.get(4)) // -> 5

    ds.setall(10)
    println(ds.get(4)) //-> 10
    println(ds.get(7)) //-> 10
    ds.set(1, 7)
    println(ds.get(1)) //-> 7

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is better, but I think HashMap might be a bit of an overkill.
The following solution might have a smaller footprint and takes less code.
Although, I would probably rather implement something more generic, it should fulfill the requirements you mentioned.

```
trait Operations {
  def get(index: Int): Int
  def set(index: Int, value: Int): Unit
  def setall(fill: Int): Unit
}

class DS(size: Int) extends Operations {
  val underlying: Array[Int] = new Array(size)

  def get(index: Int): Int = underlying(index)

  def set(index: Int, value: Int): Unit = underlying(index) = value

  def setall(fill: Int): Unit = (0 until size).foreach(underlying(_) = fill)
}
```

Alternative, which just might give us a better 'setall' complexity but at a cost ...

```
trait Operations {
  def get(index: Int): Int
  def set(index: Int, value: Int): Unit
  def setall(fill: Int): Unit
}

class DS(size: Int) extends Operations {
  var underlying: Array[Integer] = new Array(size)
  var default: Integer = new Integer(0)

  def get(index: Int): Int = {
    val result = underlying(index)
    if (result == null) default else result
  }

  def set(index: Int, value: Int): Unit = underlying(index) = value

  def setall(fill: Int): Unit = {
    default = fill
    underlying = new Array(size)
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your `set` and `setAll` are not in constant time complexity. They are both linear. I'm not quite sure about the `get` method thought

Comment: @eliasah. `set` looks totally O(1) to me (array update). But I agree with you on `setAll`

Comment: True to that! I got confused with the fact that it needed array `tail`

Comment: To make everything O(1), make `underlying` an `Array[Option[Int]]`, where `None` means that that index has not been explicitly set.  Then have `setAll` set a default which gets used for `None` values.

Comment: Thought about that, but wouldn't I still have to fill the initial array with `None`? Otherwise, it starts with `null` for all elements, which gets pretty ugly pretty fast. However, I'll added an alternative that makes use of the initial `null` entries of an `Array[_ <: AnyRef]. I don't like that very much, though.